# Peculiar Reverse Cascading in CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've got a situation where my CSS is applying styles that don't apply to the object being styled. Here is **exact** code from my site.css file...

```
.rules aside {  
    width: 270px;  
    right: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    float: left;
}

.rules aside h3 { 
    border-bottom-width: 2px; 
    border-bottom-style: solid; 
    border-bottom-color: #2A2A2A; 

    padding-bottom: 6px; 
    padding-top: 11px; 

    margin-bottom: 0px; 

    color: #F0E29A; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    letter-spacing: -0.5px; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
}
```

Now here is some HTML that utilizes it...

```
<article class="content rules">
   <section>
   // ...
   </section>
   <aside>
     Some Content
   </aside>
</article>
```

And here is the CSS markup that Chrome's Inspector shows for the `<aside>` element..

```
.rules aside {
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #2A2A2A;
padding-bottom: 6px;
padding-top: 11px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: #F0E29A;
font-size: 14px;
letter-spacing: -0.5px;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 270px;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
float: left;
}
```

This doesn't make any sense. Only an `<h3>` element should be styled from the `.rules aside h3` selector. Yet it is cascading down into the root `<aside>` element. I have other instances of this happening as well. This is happening in Google Chrome (latest version)

Including screenshots for proof.
[image]
[image]

---

*thirtydot edit:*

> [jsfiddle.net/2hnLx](http://jsfiddle.net/2hnLx) - running this
>   exact same code from an .html file on
>   my machine yields the problem results,
>   but running it from jsFiddle yields
>   the expected results. – Stacey

The code from the jsFiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" > 
<head> 
    <title>jsFiddle Example</title> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
        article, section, aside, header, nav { display: block; }

        #container { 
            margin: 0px auto; 
            width: 960px; 
            position: relative;
        }
        section { 
            float: left;
            width: 685px; 
            left: 0px; 

            background-color: #ccc;
        }
        section h2 {
            padding: 10px;
        }
        section h3 { 
            font-size: 32px; 
            color: #ffcc00; 
            font-weight: bold; 
            padding: 10px; 
            border-bottom-width: 2px; 
            border-bottom-style: solid; 
            border-bottom-color: #2A2A2A; 
            margin-bottom: 18px; 
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        .rules aside {  
            width: 270px;  
            right: 0px; 
            top: 0px; 
            float: left;

            background-color: #000;
        }

        aside h3 { 
            border-bottom-width: 2px; 
            border-bottom-style: solid; 
            border-bottom-color: #2A2A2A; 

            padding-bottom: 6px; 
            padding-top: 11px; 

            margin-bottom: 0px; 

            color: #F0E29A; 
            font-size: 14px; 
            letter-spacing: -0.5px; 
            text-transform: uppercase; 

            background-color: #fff;
        }
    </style> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div id="container"> 
        <article> 
            <section> 
                <p>Section Text</p> 
            </section> 
            <aside> 
                <p>Aside Text</p> 
            </aside> 
        </article> 
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Looks weird. The only thing that comes to mind is some crazy invisible control characters messing up the closing `}` of the first block, thus fusing the blocks.

Comment: And this only happens with Chrome?

Comment: @Ajweb: This happens in FireFox and Safari, as well. So I'm not entirely crazy? This is irregular behavior?

Comment: Just a hunch: have you set your `aside` to `display: block`? I feel like it might have something to do with using an HTML5 element and the browser treating it like an inline element.

Comment: A negative on `display: block` fixing it. Just tried it with the same results. What is more, I have `similar` code for the `<section>` element, and it works fine. Also, if I click on a root `<h3>` element, it finds the appropriate style in all three browsers.

Comment: Maybe the browser is taking `rules aside` literally? :)

Comment: @Pekka: Lol. I would upvote, but I hit the limit today.

Comment: Okay, I have just done a confirm, this _is_ in chrome only. I was looking at the wrong thing in the other browsers. I have updated to the latest version of chrome, and it persists. It is also present everywhere, not just in the `<aside>` like I had thought, it just wasn't showing as obviously in the other areas.

Comment: @Stacey: Can you recreate this on jsfiddle.net and send us a link so we can play around with it?

Comment: @Stacey: Perhaps just edit your question with the entire HTML page you're using in your screenshot. It could possibly not happen on jsFiddle.

Comment: No, I can't. Making it jsFiddle produces the proper results. But I've combed my code over and over and it runs fine everywhere but Chrome. I copied and pasted code verbatim into jsfiddle and it works fine in Chrome there, too.

Comment: I have given you 100% of the code that is on that specific page. The only things not given aren't related, and even commenting them out completely does not change the results. I can't really add it all into a single question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2hnLx/ - running this exact same code from an .html file on my machine yields the problem results, but running it from jsFiddle yields the expected results.

Comment: @Stacey: I guessed it might not happen on jsFiddle. I can't recreate your problem using your new code. It looks the same in Chrome (10.0.648.18) and Firefox. I'm going to edit your question with the code from jsFiddle.

Comment: It only appears to be the debugger that is really problematic. The actual styles themselves do not seem to be getting applied, it just shows wrong in the debugger.

Comment: If the styles themselves are not being applied, then the issue is a bug with Google Chrome (or it's Dev. Tools). I would file a bug report to the Google Chrome team.

Comment: Yes, I just submitted it as a bug, let's see how far that goes. Even IE9 beta shows it all properly. I've never noticed it until today, though. Even at that, it's very hard to reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.
It was the BOM. Try to save site.css file as UTF-8 without BOM, and it will work.

**Update**
This is inherent: [UTF-8 HTML and CSS files with BOM (and how to remove the BOM with Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456380/utf-8-html-and-css-files-with-bom-and-how-to-remove-the-bom-with-python)

Comment: Is there any way to tell Visual Studio to use this UTF-8 encoding for the files by default?

Comment: Thank you. You were correct, and this was the problem. This can be solved by going to `File`->`Advanced Save Options` and selecting `UTF-8 (without signature)` as the Encoding. Still, I don't know who to be more frustrated at, Microsoft, for making this the default in Visual Studio and having no way to set a new default per document type, or Chrome, for not being able to handle what FireFox, IE, Safari, and Opera can just fine. I suppose seeing as how Chrome is free, I should probably alert Microsoft before I alert Google as a 'problem', but this is a pretty annoying problem to have.

Comment: I greatly appreciate all of your help, as well, for actually _trying_ to figure it out, instead of brushing me aside with a crazy 'Hey, check your CSS, you probably just did it wrong'. I have to say it is kind of warming to come to a community, pose a problem, and have actual _debate_ about the cause instead of someone simply pointing their finger at me saying _'You made a mistake'_. Another reason why StackOverflow is the best website in the world, in my opinion, and should be even higher than facebook! =)

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this in Chrome 9. I am not able to reproduce the bug.
Here there is my code (you can try it): http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20195191/StackOverflow/so_4945633.html

And this is a screenshot from Chrome. [image: screenshot of css properties]

Comment: Nothing :) I made a page in jsfiddle, but it changes the source code. Then, I saw that the original post just has a link to jsfiddle. Now I changed my answer.

Comment: I am by _no_ means an expert at HTML or CSS, but I am well versed enough to know that _something_ strange is going on here. I will keep trying to exactly reproduce this bug outside of my project, maybe that will let me trace down what in my own project is causing it.

Comment: If you are able to reproduce it, please post a page in DropBox or something similar, so we can try it.

Comment: I have reproduced the issue... sort of. My styles are fine, it only appears if I link styles using the `@import url('url');` code within a `.css` file. It doesn't seem to matter what the imported file has.

Comment: I have confirmed the problem, and posted about it up above.