# How to convert a unicode object to a string or a python dictionary

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

As a result of an [API call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512402.aspx) I get the following object of `<type 'unicode'>`:

```
{"From":"en","Translations":[{"Count":0,"MatchDegree":100,"MatchedOriginalText":"","Rating":5,"TranslatedText":"Cómo estás"}]}
```

but when I try to parse it with `simplejson_loads()` I get this error:

```
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

How can I handle this kind of objects?

**EDIT II**: the JSON is correct. What messes up things is the BOM at the beginning of the string. Trying to get rid of it with `.encode('utf-8-sig')` produces the error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

but somewhere in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456380/utf-8-html-and-css-files-with-bom-and-how-to-remove-the-bom-with-python) I found a solution that worked for me:

```
if u.startswith(u'\ufeff'):
  u = u[1:]
```

And I'm quite tempted to just get away with it and be happy.

Comment: can't reproduce.  `import json; json.loads(u'that string')` gives me back the expected `dict`.

Comment: @roippi you're right. It looks like an encoding issue. I edited the question with further informations...

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse just the JSON, whatever is between the very first **{** and the very last **}**.

If that is not enough, please give us more details.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I do try to parse the whole thing, that is from the very first { and the very last }, and I reported the error I get. There is nothing but that JSON in the API response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import asp

foo = ast.literal_eval(your_result)
```

This will convert unicode object to python dictionary, is that your solution?

Comment: `literal_eval()` works (as well as `json.loads()` ) but only if I remove the BOM first. Turned out that was the source of all problems...